# Installation on a ZFS filesystem missing in the installer

Tags: system-installation, filesystem, zfs

There is no ZFS file system option while creating file system but as per release note it supports ZFS. So why this option not available. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

What Ubuntu 16.04 did was include it in the kernel and the distribution, so you don't have to add extra PPAs anymore or build modules with DKMS everytime there is a new kernel update.

This is a big deal.

Integrating it with the installer is a natural next step, but it wasn't done in time for the 16.04 release. Maybe in a point release in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you cant directly install you have to migrate
https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-16.04-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Schrijver - On the ZFSonlinux Github site there are multiple how-to's for creating a ZFS striped pool mirrors & installing Ubuntu 16.04 on it.

The one I followed is this:
[Ubuntu 16.04 Root on ZFS](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu%2016.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS)

I followed that URL for the past 5 days & finally got a ZFS striped pool mirrors of 4 2TB disks configured & installed ubuntu 16.04 on it... BUT... that URL is **not** for the faint hearted or any new-bies !

I'm also not sure its totally accurate as what I ended up with.. while it does boot 16.04 OK and the "zpool status" does show the mirrored pool configured & active... I've seen other weird stuff like GParted reports 2 of the partitions his guide creates (/dev/sda2 & /dev/sda9) as **unknown**.   I opened a bug with GParted thinking it might be a problem with it but the GParted Dev's are starting to convince me otherwise.

I had also found the URL you mentioned

[HOWTO install Ubuntu 16.04 to a Native ZFS Root Filesystem](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-16.04-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem)

I have not tried that one yet.

***The ONLY official Ubuntu documentation*** regarding creation of a ZFS striped pool (versus using raidz) is this:

[Ubuntu Wiki - ZFS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ZFS)

However, the instructions there for creating a striped pool use commands that are contradicted by the URL you posted:

Ubuntu's Wiki says to used disk ID's  sdX  (ie sda, sdb, sdc, sdd)

whereas the Github documentation I followed (reference #1) specifically says in section 2.2:

> Always use the long /dev/disk/by-id/* aliases with ZFS. Using the
>   /dev/sd* device nodes directly can cause sporadic import failures,
>   especially on systems that have more than one storage pool

So I'm not sure which is correct.  You & I would assume that we should follow Canonical/Ubuntu's own documentation.   Yet the zfsonlinux github guides differ in many ways from what the Ubuntu Documentation states.

I may go back to BTRFS raid10 until ZFSonlinux & Ubuntu mature a bit more as fighting documentation like this is too time consuming to trial & error everything... when I'd rather just be doing work.   The BTRFS worked great for me for the past 2 years?

Just thought I'd point out some of the difficulties I've found trying to get Ubuntu 16.04 & ZFS striped pool mirror's working together.